# Unbalanced Fault Problem

Tags: power, three-phase, fault

[image]

[image]

I have attached the image of a theoretical question with its explanation given in my book. can anyone please explain this ?

I am not able to start from anywhere so I can't show my work. I am posting this to genuinely learn about faults.

Comment: Easy, study the unbalanced faults and sequence components, you will easily read the posted question.

Comment: I have studied the basics but I am not able to understand this. @Hazem, Please can you explain me the explanation given in the solution.

Comment: @Hazem, please take a look https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349472/ordinary-differential-relay-problem